# Differential of transposed matrices

Tags: matrices, derivatives, trace

I'm puzzling about how to deal with the differential of a transposed matrix.
I was wondering if there is some rule such that $d(X^{T}) = (dX)^{T}$.

In general I work with derivation on the trace of a matrix and I get sometimes the following situation:
$$ tr(d(X^{T})AX + Bd(X^{T})CX + DdX) $$
where X can be a rectangular matrix.

I'm quite sure that such expression can be rearranged as follows:
$$ tr((AX + CXB)d(X^{T})) + tr(DdX) $$

Clearly I would like to obtain something like $tr(J(X)dX)$ for derivative, but I'm not able to go on.

Some suggestion?

Comment: What is the definition of $d(X)$?

Comment: it is the differential of X

Comment: I know, but what is the definition?

Comment: Apparently the property you want is true: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus#Identities_in_differential_form

Comment: well, it represents the change in the linearization of a function with respect to the change of some other thing.

Comment: This seems to be how to define $\mathrm{d}$ on a matrix: $\mathrm{d}(a_{ij})=(\mathrm{d}a_{ij})$. That seems to give what you want, does it not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The relation $d(X^T) = d(X)^T$ is true.

You can easily verify this by letting $X$ be a square matrix and then by comparing the left and right hand side of above the relation.

Comment: This answer could use more explanation. It also does not apply to the stated case that $A$ may be rectangular.

Comment: Any operation which merely rearranges the elements of $X$, (e.g. vec, transpose, reshape, vecpose, block-vecpose) satisfies the differential property.  It rearranges the elements of $dX$ in the same way.