# Derivation wrt a vector variable: what happens to transpose of the vector?

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus

Considering $x,y$ are vectors and $\mu,\Sigma$ are mean (vector) and covariance (matrix); how to solve:

$(1): \displaystyle \frac{\partial }{\partial X}{[(y-x-\mu_N)^T\Sigma_N^{-1}(y-x-\mu_N) + (x-\mu_X)^T \Sigma_X^{-1}(x-\mu_X))]}=0$

I have the final answer which first simplifies as:

$(2):-\Sigma_N^{-1}(y-x-\mu_N)+\Sigma_X^{-1}(x-\mu_X)=0$

And then:

$(3): x=(\Sigma_N^{-1}+\Sigma_N^{-1})^{-1}(\Sigma_N^{-1}(y-\mu_N)+\Sigma_X^{-1}\mu_X) $

from $(2)$ to $(3)$ is obvious. But when I simplify $(1)$, I can't get to $(2)$ and I have extra terms with $x^T$ in my equation before taking the derivative. As I know ([reference1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/252276/differential-of-transposed-matrices), [reference2](http://www.ee.ic.ac.uk/hp/staff/dmb/matrix/proof002.html#dXinv_xij_p)):

$\displaystyle \frac{\partial }{\partial x}x^T={[\displaystyle \frac{\partial }{\partial x}x]}^T$

so those extra terms can not be eliminated. If I eliminate those terms with only $x^T$ after taking derivative, I exactly get to $(2)$ then $(3)$.

Any idea what's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $(\mu_X, \mu_N)$ are vectors, and you are adding them to $(X,Y)$ -- then the latter must also be vectors (not matrices).  So I'll denote them by $(x,y)$.

Define a few variables for convenience, and ease of typing 
$$\eqalign{
 A &= \Sigma_N^{-1} \cr
 B &= \Sigma_X^{-1} \cr
 a &= y-x-\mu_N \cr
 b &= x-\mu_X \cr
}$$
In terms of these variables, the function can be written as
$$\eqalign{
 f &= a^TAa + b^TBb \cr
   &= A:aa^T + B:bb^T
}$$
where the colons denote the [Frobenius product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication#Frobenius_product).

Taking the differential
$$\eqalign{
 df &= A:d(aa^T) + B:d(bb^T) \cr
    &= A:(da\,a^T+a\,da^T) + B:(db\,b^T+b\,db^T) \cr
    &= (A+A^T)\,a:da + (B+B^T)\,b:db \cr
    &= 2A\,a:da + 2B\,b:db \cr
    &= 2\,A\,a:(-dx) + 2\,B\,b:dx \cr
}$$
Since $df=\big(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}:dx\big),\,$ the gradient is
$$\eqalign{
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} &= 2\,(B\,b-A\,a) \cr\cr
}$$
Setting this to zero yields equation (2).

Comment: is $$\eqalign{
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} &= 2\,(B\,b-A\,a) \cr\cr
}$$ valid for a different $a$ as well? for example, if $a=y-Mx- \mu_N$, where $M$ is a constant matrix, the gradient should still be the same, right? and similarly at the end we will have $$\eqalign{
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} &= 2\,(B\,b-MA\,a) \cr\cr
}$$

Comment: Not quite.  $da=-M\,dx$ so the relevant term from the differential becomes $$A\,a:M\,dx=M^TA\,a:dx\ne M\,A\,a:dx$$  So the term in the gradient is $(M^TA\,a)$ not $(M\,A\,a)$.